# Issues with running multiple cron jobs

Tags: php, redirect, cron

I am working on a project where I need to run 12 different PHP files, every night.  11 of these files are pulling data, each from a different external site and reformatting it into an XML file, for my purposes.  The 12th file, combines the 11 XML files into a master XML file.

I had originally had these combined into a single PHP file but, it was far too much and kept timing out.  They work fine, separated as they are.

I'm on a GoDaddy shared hosting plan and started setting up cron jobs to run these files every night.  However, GoDaddy limits you to 10 cron jobs total.

So, as an alternative, I placed a header redirect at the bottom of the first 10 files (obviously the last file doesn't need a redirect), to redirect to the next one and run it. This consolidates 11 cron jobs down to 1.

```
// On to the next
header('Location: http://www.domain.com/secondFile.php');
```

I did not realize, at the time, that header redirects only work in the browser, not in cron jobs.  I'm getting a **302 Moved Temporarily** message.

What other options do I have here?  Are there redirects that **will** work in cron jobs?

Any info provided is appreciated.

---

---

Thanks to **Barmar**'s help, I've got it working now.  Posting the format here for anyone else having the same issue, on GoDaddy hosting.

**generatexml.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh
/web/cgi-bin/php5 /home/content/u/s/e/username/html/firstFile.php
/web/cgi-bin/php5 /home/content/u/s/e/username/html/secondFile.php
/web/cgi-bin/php5 /home/content/u/s/e/username/html/thirdFile.php
```

etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run a single cron job containing a shell script to run each of the PHP scripts:

```
#!/bin/sh
php firstFile.php
php secondFile.php
...
```

Comment: Perhaps you can provide some more info. I've never worked with shell scripts before and don't know how well they work on shared hosting. I created my .sh file, using the format you show above (using absolute paths) and uploaded it.  Then I setup a cron to run it. However, the report is showing me a 'Permission denied' error.

Comment: I'm not experienced with shared hosting services. You need to make sure the script has execute permissions.

Comment: Well, I added execute permissions and that error went away.  Now I'm getting '/bin/sh^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory'. So, per this ( http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/3483/what-is-a-cron-job ) I changed the path.  Now I'm getting this error: /web/cgi-bin/php5^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

Comment: Your file has Windows CRLF line breaks, instead of Unix LF. You need to convert the file format or use a file transfer protocol that translates automatically.

Comment: Well, we're getting closer. No more errors since changing to Unix. However, in the report, it just seems to be echoing the text in the .sh file, rather than actually running the php files I've listed -- php firstFile.php php secondFile.php (on separate lines, obviously).

Answer (score 1):

run the script via your webserver and `wget`.

Comment: Given the errors I've mentioned in the comments below, I'm not entirely sure how to setup wget either.